# How can I use the same name for a method in my class as a method on another class I am using internally?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project for school and got stuck on one particular part.

We are creating a `SortedList` class that is supposed to implement the java interface Collection.

The thing is, our instructor said we could use the methods from other classes such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` to define most of the methods we'd have to otherwise define manually.

How do I use methods like `size()` from the `ArrayList` class to use in the size method of my `SortedList` class?

I guess I'm just wondering how I would make a method with the same name as the one in the `ArrayList` class while calling upon the one from the `ArrayList` class inside it.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
public class SortedList<T> {

  //Used this List as part of the implementation of SortedList
  private List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();


  /**
   * Here you implement your SortedList size() method by using your
   * List<Integer> myList as the implementation of it.
   */
  public int size() {
       return myList.size();
  }

}
```

Comment: Exactly.  The `size()` method in your `ArrayList` object is not the same method as the `size()` method in your own class.  You can use the same name for your method because it refers to your code, not that of the inside object.

Answer (score 2):

So,

```
ArrayList yourArrayList = new ArrayList(); // creation of instance of ArrayList
SortedList yourSortedList = new SortedList(); // creation of instance of SortedList

yourArrayList.size() // will access the size() method of ArrayList
yourSortedList.size() // will access the size() method of SortedList
```

Objects of a class type will access the method of their respective class.

Comment: Not exactly.  You would need an instance of `ArrayList` and an instance of `SortedList`, as in `myArrayList` and `mySortedList`.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should have made that clearer.